# Button in Excel to copy information about specific month from other table

Tags: vba, excel, button, powerquery

So I have one big table, that includes a lot of information. What I need is to make a button or something else, that would copy information from this massive table by date, for example, only purchases made in November. Here's a principle of what I have and what should I get.

This button would copy that data and paste it into other sheet. Would be nice If there could be month list like with data validation, where I select the month and then press the button and it shows all those purchases made in that month.

This is an example of the big massive table

[image: http://i.imgur.com/CUnKQ3C.png]

This is what I would like to get by using the button and select drop down menu

[image: http://i.imgur.com/MyaLBwR.png]

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Post the code you are struggling with.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? We like to have a code (which is not working for some reason) to start from. That's how we could teach you and not to do the work for you. As you are new, please read our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you haven't got anything yet, google 'Excel VBA filter data and copy to another sheet' or alternatively, use the Macro Recorder to get you started.  Or start here for some inspiration --> [Excel Macros - Copy and paste filtered rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829968/excel-macros-copy-and-paste-filtered-rows)

Comment: I got something something like this, but I only know the basics of VBA and I need this done. So I used this example and changed few variables, but I dont quite understand why It doesnt do a think. Sorry, but I'm new to programming in VBA :/

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win006_2.htm


Heres the code - 
https://shrib.com/beZ02kGL

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Table to achieve this.  Select the top-left cell (labelled "Nr.") and from the Insert ribbon choose Table. Providing you have no gaps in rows and columns this will automatically select all your data.

Then you can use the Filter button on the row heading for Date.  Date values in the cells will enable Date Filter options as shown in the screen-shot below.  The right-click options will meet most requirements, or you can use the Custom Filter option to enter specific date ranges.  No code is required.

[image: Excel table - Date Filter options]